# Computing a complicated double integral

Tags: calculus

I want to compute the following double integral:

$$\int_{-1}^{0}\int_{-1}^{q}\delta(s+a)\sinh[k(q-s)]dsdq$$

where $0<a<1$
I *think* it is the following:
$$\int_{-1}^{0}\int_{-1}^{q}\delta(s+a)\sinh[k(q-s)]dsdq=\int_{-1}^{0}\sinh[k(q+a)]dq$$
I'm not sure though.

Comment: The lower limit of the last integral must be "$-a$".

Comment: Why must it be $-a$?

Comment: Hint: what is $\int_2^3\delta(x-1)f(x)\,dx$?

Comment: $f(1)$, I don't see your point.

Comment: Thank you for your help, you've been very clear.

Comment: So does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

First split from $a$ point:
$$\begin{equation}\begin{split}
& \int_{-1}^0 \int_{-1}^q \delta(s+a) \sinh [k(q-s)] ds dq = \\
& \int_{-1}^{-a} \int_{-1}^q \delta(s+a) \sinh [k(q-s)] ds dq + \int_{-a}^0 \int_{-1}^q \delta(s+a) \sinh [k(q-s)] ds dq
\end{split}\end{equation}$$
Now in first integral, $s$ (almost) never meets $-a$, because $s \leqslant q \leqslant -a$. So it become $0$, by definition of Dirac Delta. And in second one $s$ (almost) always meet $-a$, secondly by definition of Dirac Delta we have:
$$\begin{equation}\begin{split}
\int_{-1}^0 \int_{-1}^q \delta(s+a) \sinh [k(q-s)] ds dq
& = \int_{-a}^0 \int_{-1}^q \delta(s+a) \sinh [k(q-s)] ds dq \\
& = \int_{-a}^0 \sinh [k(q+a)] dq = \frac{1}{k} \cosh[k(q+a)]_{-a}^0 \\
& = \frac{1}{k} (\cosh(ka) - 1)
\end{split}\end{equation}$$